# Why is the loop cut tool stopping at one face?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I'm having an issue with a loop cut in the image below. The face I'm having the issue is the following:

[image]

For other hand my intention is to have the part in blue in the below image totally straight and not curved:

[image]

This is the reason I want to loop cut the entire perimeter and move in the Z axis all the edges to make it straight.

I already cleaned up duplicated vertex and the normals are alright but I don't know why is not loop cutting all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but keep in mind that loop cutting only works in quads. What you seem to have there is an "ngon" ==> An ngon is a face or polygon that is made up of five or more sides or edges connected by five or more vertices. Anything over a quad (4 sides) is considered an ngon. So notice in your screenshots that the loop cut worked perfectly where you had faces with 4 vertices and (if what I am seeing is correct) where the interruption happens you have a face with 7 vertices. Try joining the 2 vertices above the ?pipe? by selecting them and pressing "J".

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the issue, there was an Ngon and I didnt know that loop cuts didnt worked with them. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that was it also for me. In my case the easiest solution was to "Dissolve vertices" by right-clicking on one vertex and then selecting that option. Once the face was back to 4 vertices, loop cut went straight through it.